# Error installing package (Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.)

Tags: laravel

I want to install a package with "composer require rpsimao/invoicexpress-api" but it appears an error:

```
Using version ^0.5.6 for rpsimao/invoicexpress-api
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for rpsimao/invoicexpress-api ^0.5.6 -> satisfiable by rpsimao/invoicexpress-api[0.5.6].
    - rpsimao/invoicexpress-api 0.5.6 requires laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.26, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.29, v5.4.3, v5.4.30, v5.4.31, v5.4.32, v5.4.33, v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Do you know how to solve that? Im using laravel 5.5, it seems that the package support that version but it appears the error.

Comment: can you post the compose.json file and whats the laravel version?

Comment: I have the version 5.5.

Comment: it requires 5.4.*

Comment: Thanks, but it says "Tested with Laravel 5.5.*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even though they said **Tested with Laravel 5.5.*** it in the readme,composer.json says it requires both

```
"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
"illuminate/support": "5.4.*",
```

so if the package's composer.json says it should be Laravel 5.4.*. You are using laravel 5.5 so it's incompatible.

here is the rpsimao/invoicexpress-api [composer.json](https://github.com/rpsimao/invoicexpress-api/blob/0.5.6/composer.json) file of tag 0.5.6. see Laravel version

```
{
    "name": "rpsimao/invoicexpress-api",
    "description": "Laravel Package to interact with InvoiceXpress API",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": [
        "laravel",
        "rpsimao",
        "invoicexpress-api",
        "invoicexpress",
        "api"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/rpsimao/invoicexpress-api",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Ricardo Simão",
            "email": "ricardo.simao@upgrade.pt"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2.1",
        "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.4.1",
        "guzzlehttp/promises": "~1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "illuminate/support": "5.4.*",
        "spatie/array-to-xml": "^2.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "rpsimao\\InvoiceXpressAPI\\": "src/"
        },
        "files":[
            "src/Helpers/invoicexpress-api.php"
        ]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.1",
        "orchestra/testbench": "^3.4"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "rpsimao\\InvoiceXpressAPI\\Test\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "rpsimao\\InvoiceXpressAPI\\InvoiceXpressAPIServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "InvoiceXpressClients": "rpsimao\\InvoiceXpressAPI\\InvoiceXpressAPIFacade"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

**AFTER EDIT**

So, currently it's not possible to use with Laravel 5.5 as Laravel 5.5 uses PHP >=7.0.0 too, this package uses Laravel 5.4 which uses PHP >=5.6.4.

And Remove composer.lock file if exists

Comment: Thanks, so is not possible to use with laravel 5.5?

Comment: Ya. see the After edit part. Laravel 5.5 uses php 7, this package and laravel 5.4 uses php >=5.6.4

Answer (score 1):

That package has not been updated to work with laravel 5.5. 
You can verify its dependency on packagist:

https://packagist.org/packages/rpsimao/invoicexpress-api#0.5.6

Invoicexpress requires laravel/framework: 5.4.*

Also the dev-master version is not suitable for laravel 5.5

> dev-master 2018-01-10 15:20 UTC requires
>
> guzzlehttp/guzzle: 
>   ^6.2.1 guzzlehttp/psr7: ^1.4.1 
>   guzzlehttp/promises: ~1.0 
>   laravel/framework: 5.4.* 
>   illuminate/support: 5.4.* 
>   php: ^7.0
>   spatie/array-to-xml: ^2.5

Comment: Thanks, so is not possible to use with laravel 5.5?

Comment: you better ask to the author on github by opening an issue... https://github.com/rpsimao/invoicexpress-api/issues

Answer (score 1):

It works on ubuntu and must be check laravel set environmental

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel BlogLaravel "7.*"
```

for composer and laravel set envrmental path

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

if are you try to install "jwt-auth" and get the error try with this code

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source

php artisan vendor:publish 

php artisan jwt:secret
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install passport via the Composer package manager and I solve this error by using  -W at the end of the command like this:

**composer require laravel/passport -W**

**-W** means with all dependencies so you can also install the packages you want without any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. remove ./composer/cache folder
2. run composer global update
```

or
**For Laravel Developer:**
Different laravel version support Different Vuejs version.
First,Findout which laravel version support vuejs version.
Than installed it.

Example:

> Laravel 7 support vuejs 2.4.
> so installed it 
> composer require laravel/ui:^2.4